# macOS: zsh option delete changes

Tags: macos, zsh

I just upgraded to macOS 10.15 and have decided to try to use zshell instead of bash. Figured, why not...

Well, it's going OK for now, but there's one thing that's *really* getting to me. I have enabled the preference to have the Option key act as the meta key and have really gotten used to being able to use "Option-Delete" to effectively remove one word at a time (ok, it's not specifically one-word, but it usually works to only remove say the last directory name when typing in a full path)

Since switching to zsh, I've noticed that the same command deletes the **entire line, up to the first space**. If I'm trying to type a full path, like `/Users/username/Desktop/Folder1/Folder2`, but mistype `Folder2` and wanted to just start over, I would normally use `option-delete` to just delete the word `Folder2`; in bash, this works fine, but now with zsh it deletes the *whole path*.

Is there a way to alter this behavior in zshell? So far this is the only thing that has been a bother so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to alphanumeric characters, Zsh considers all characters in `$WORDCHARS` to be part of a word. By default, `$WORDCHARS` is equal to `*?_-.[]~=/&;!#$%^(){}<>`. As you can see, this includes `/`.

By adding

```bsh
WORDCHARS=''
```

to your `~/.zshrc` file, you can get the behavior you want.

### Shameless Plug

Because I, too, think that Zsh's default word editing behavior is subpar, I wrote a plugin to improve it even further: https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-edit

Feel free to try it. :)

Comment: thankyouthankyouthankyou this was driving me bonkers